# Issue to pass an object

Tags: r

I'm new in "R" and i have a problem to keep a variable changed. Here is my code :

```
recursiveCall <- function(x, N)
{
    x[2^(N-1)+1] <- x[2^(N-1)+1] + (x[1] + x[2^N+1] ) / 2 
    if (N>1) {
        recursiveCall(x[1..2^(N-1)+1], N-1)
        recursiveCall(x[2^(N-1)+1..N], N-1)
    }
    #cat("Wmodif = ", x, "\n")
}
PaulLevyBrownianMotion <- function(N)
{
    cat("Paul Levy construction for N = ", N, "\n")
    W = rnorm(2^N+1, 0, 1)
    W[1] <- 0
    cat("Wstandard = ", W, "\n")
    recursiveCall(W, N)
    return (W) 
}
```

But the W doesn't remember the change in the successive recursiveCall. What should I write to keep the second line similar to the third in the output ? Also if you have any suggestion about my code, I'll be glad to hear them.

Here is what I'm trying to do with the first answer :

```
recursiveCall <- function(x, N)
{
    x[2^(N-1)+1] <- x[2^(N-1)+1] + (x[1] + x[2^N+1] ) / 2 
    if (N>1) {
        x[1:2^(N-1)+1] <- [recursiveCall(x[1:2^(N-1)+1], N-1)
        x[2^(N-1)+1:2^N] <- recursiveCall(x[2^(N-1)+1:2^N], N-1)
    }
    #cat("Wmodif = ", x, "\n")
    return x
}
PaulLevyBrownianMotion <- function(N)
{
    cat("Paul Levy construction for N = ", N, "\n")
    W = rnorm(2^N+1, 0, 1)
    W[1] <- 0
    cat("Wstandard = ", W, "\n")
    W <- recursiveCall(W, N)
    return (W) 
}
```

Thanks, Niels

Comment: `?"<<-"` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: perhaps, I don't know how to use it

Comment: <<- should *not* be what he's looking for.

Comment: In your modification of the first answer you have an extra "[" on the first line inside the `if` statement, just before `recursiveCall` and `return()` is a function, you need to pass x to it, `return(x)`. You *can* make recursion work this way.

Answer (score 2):

Arguments are passed by value in R (there's more to say about it, but this will work as a primer). So changing them within a function does not change the 'outer' version of them.
For what you want, change

```
recursiveCall <- function(x, N)
{
    x[2^(N-1)+1] <- x[2^(N-1)+1] + (x[1] + x[2^N+1] ) / 2 
    cat("Wmodif = ", x, "\n")
    return(x)
}
```

And then you use this as:

```
PaulLevyBrownianMotion <- function(N)
{
    cat("Paul Levy construction for N = ", N, "\n")
    W = rnorm(2^N+1, 0, 1)
    W[1] <- 0
    cat("Wstandard = ", W, "\n")
    W<-recursiveCall(W, N)
    return (W) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However as my function must be recursive in the end, this won't work I guess. I edited my code with a better code, if you don't mind having a look :)